# SQL Response unclear

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-connection

I am trying to access a locally setup MySQL database from a remote location using port forwarding.

The remote location is using my external IP address and the port 3306. I have tried accessing this IP:Port combo from outside of my network at get this"

```
Q���
5.7.4-m14-log�+���-FYn<~*Q�ÿ÷!�ÿ€����������9j,9yvdr3D<A�mysql_native_password�!��ÿ„#08S01Got packets out of order
```

Does this indicate an error? I ask because my external software is showing my a connection error, as in it can't even make a connection. I have the J connector installed just fine and it has worked in the past. Not sure what to try next.

I also get the same response on the local machine by typing 127.0.0.1:3306 into a browser.

Thanks